# Using mailx command not able to send email

Tags: shell, email, aix

I am using mailx command to send email in my script and mailx function is behaving preety weird.As for some mailx commands are sending emails while others are not.
Here is the one which did work from script itself.

```
mailx -r MSAR_COPY -s "MSAR COPY - Error starting due to existence of ERRORFILE from previous run" $MAILLIST
```

But other one didn't trigger email so i even tried simply sending email from shell.that too seems to be not working.

```
 va10puvfns001b(fnsw)/home/fnsw/bin/msar_copies> mailx -r MSAR_COPY -s "MSAR COPY -Error starting as FileNet is down" gaurav.pareek@wellpoint.com

  (Interrupt -- one more to kill letter)
```

Once i hitenter after entering the command it starts clocking, and i need to kill it after some time manually using ctrl+c .Then i get    (Interrupt -- one more to kill letter)   thing and once again i need to give ctrl+c to get to prompt.
Any ideas why it is not working all the time?

And here is the output of script in debug mode:

- echo All MSAR file systems are in use. Once the currently used file system is full, there will be no more file systems to use for copying msar dat files. Start the
  process to get a new file system ASAP.
- 1> /home/fnsw/bin/msar_copies/WARNFILE

  - mailx -r MSAR_COPY -s MSAR COPY - All File Systems are in use filenet.admin@wellpoint.com
- 0< /home/fnsw/bin/msar_copies/WARNFILE

  - cut -d  -f2 /home/fnsw/bin/msar_copies/msar_fs.out
  - - awk {print $1}
  - grep /msar21 /home/fnsw/bin/msar_copies/msar_fs.out
    full=0
  - [[ 0 -gt 33544232 ]]
  - flag=1
  - [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
  - echo Exiting because there is not enough free space for the copy
  - 1> /home/fnsw/bin/msar_copies/ERRORFILE
  - mailx -r MSAR_COPY -s MSAR COPY - URGENT ERROR-Destination Folder does not have enough space.Need to request a new file system right away. filenet.admin@wellpoint.com
  - 0< /home/fnsw/bin/msar_copies/ERRORFILE
  - exit 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for 2-3 hours i came to know that issue was due to some special characters in  some mailx commands.

I removed some of mailx line from script and rewrote them and ran the script.It is working fine now.